# Почему массив, перебираемый в foreach, не удается обрезать при каждом проходе цикла с помощью сессии?

Tags: php, циклы, сессия, foreach, итераторы

Написал скрипт, который должен обрезать массив на накапливаемое в сессии число элементов. Цифра в сессии накапливается с каждым запуском программы, но вот обрезки массива не происходит. Почему? Не понимаю.. (

Если врдампить сессию, то, действительно, прибавляет с каждым перезапуском программы. Что-то происходит в районе array_slice().

В моем варианте выдает ошибку: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS) in W:\domains\localhost\par.php on line 19

```
if (isset($_SESSION["time"])) {
    /*var_dump($_SESSION["time"]);*/
}

foreach ((array_slice($matches[0], $_SESSION["time"], 0, true) as $key => $value) {

       if (is_string($value)) {
        /*var_dump(substr($value, 21));*/
    $cut = substr($value, 128);
    $output = 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user=&key=&query=' . urlencode($cut) . '&lr==ru&sortby=&filter=none&maxpassages=5&groupby=ocs-in-group%3D3';

    $result = file_get_contents($output);
      echo '<pre>';
      var_dump($value);
      var_dump($result);
      echo '</pre>';
       $fp = fopen("xml.txt", "a+");
     fwrite($fp, $result);
       fclose($fp);
       sleep(0.30);
      /* echo "<pre>";
       var_dump($result);
       echo "</pre>";*/
   }

    if($key == 10) {
          $key = $key + 1;
          break;
}

 }
$steam = $key;
$_SESSION["time"] += $steam;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас явная ошибка в коде. Разбейте условие с `foreach` на более простую структуру. Например `$tmp = array_slice($matches[0], $_SESSION["time"], 0, true);`, а затем `foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) ` и посмотрите что будет.
`

Comment: `((array_slice($matches[0], $_SESSION["time"], 0, true) as $key => $value)` - открывающих скобок 3 а закрывающих только 2.. удалите лишнюю сковку вначале

Comment: открывающих скобок также три..

Comment: Попробовал положить результаты array_slice ы переменную.. и уже одну переменную вставить statement foreach - массив не оберзается и не показывается вообще, а в консоли нет ошибок..

Comment: У меня array_slice передвигается по массиву, подчиняясь счетчику в сессии, но если выводить переменную $tmp, то она "вардампит" только первый элемент обрезанного массива, а не весь массив..

Comment: Подозреваю, что тут дело в том, что каждый элемент массива является сам массивом.. Результаты выложил в виде скриншота в текст вопроса внизу..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась:
Не совсем понял, из-за каких действий.

1. Вот тут: $cut = substr($value, 128);

заменил 128 на 1.. может просто результат полностью обрезался и поэтому код не отрабатывал, как нужно..

2. Также, может быть, зависал ли браузер, либо сервер...